# Does Google Analytics track images changed with javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, google-analytics

I have the following piece of HTML which changes the image on the page with the image selected by the user:

**HTML**:

```
<input name="photo" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="changePhoto(this.files[0])">
<img id='image' src="starting.png"/>
```

It uses this piece of **javascript**:

```
function changePhoto(submitted_file) {
    document.getElementById('image').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(submitted_file);
}
```

If I add Google Analytics, does the selected image get uploaded on Google servers? I am trying to understand this for privacy purposes.

Answer (score 1):

No, google analytics will not track the image change OR upload the image to Google's servers.

Comment: Thanks. Would you have any more insights on this?